# Trying to add setOnClickListener in Button but it is giving error "Cannot resolve symbol 'setOnClickListener'"

Tags: android

I'm trying to learn android programming using the new Android Studio.Trying to set setOnClickListener method in Button but it is giving error..."Cannot resolve symbol'setOnClickListener'"

Thank in advance for your helps.

---

trying to add image of my code but i do not have 10 reputation, so i had put it on onedrive..below is the link can any one helps here to add image in my question..

https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=8103B2FA442B96E9&id=8103B2FA442B96E9%21162&v=3

Comment: You can't write code outside directly in a class. Put it inside a method and it would work.

Comment: Why can't you copy the code instead of its image ? A image of code makes no sense.

Comment: Please copy the code instead of linking to animage

Comment: Indrajeet - Posting an image limits what people can do with the code. More importantly, it reduces *your* chances of getting assistance. If someone has to retype all of your code in order to review/test it, they probably won't bother. So it is better to post the actual code. (Images are better for when you need to represent complex concepts or show graphical features).

Comment: Hi @Leigh,

First of all : Thank you so much for your guidance. 

I am new here and this is my first question. Your guidance help to understand way of drafting question as well as advantage about it.

Once again thank you so much....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your button code in the onCreate method. It will work.

Comment: Does this answer act as a general solution to this problem, or was it specific to OPs particular code? (the image has been removed)

Answer (score 0):

insted of using setOnClickListener you can set an onClick attribute in xml layout like this:

```
<Button 
   android:layout_width="100dp"
   android:layout_height="100dp"
   android:text="Button"
   android:onClick="btn_clicked"
   />
```

then in java class create btn_clicked method like this:

```
 public void btn_clicked(View v)
 {
     //write on clicked code here
 }
```

in this scenario you dont need to imprement setOnClickListener  :)